# How to delete element and also shift the $key in array

Tags: php

I have an array looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1213059
    [1] => 1213063
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 1213072
)
```

I would like to make it as following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1213059
    [1] => 1213063
    [2] => 1213072
)
```

Is there anyone can help me?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Check [demo](http://codepad.org/SwHTpfmh) here:

`array_values(array_filter($your_array));` to keep your keys numerically .

Comment: its `array_filter()` instead of `array_filer()`

Answer (score 4):

[`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/array_filter) will remove all elements that evaluate to false:

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think answers above give correct fields order, as it was asked. If you only want to remove some fields from array and leave keys order untouched you could do it with

`array_filter($arr) or with unset($arr[$i])`

But if you want to get new order of keys, so there is no "holes", in above example to set key 4 to key 2 as keys 2 and 3 are unset, you have to use

```
ksort($arr)
```

Here is a complete example:

```
$arr=array(1,1,3,2,0);
print_r($arr);
echo '<br>';
unset($arr[2]);
ksort($arr);
print_r($arr);
$arr=array_values($arr);#EDITED
```

`ksort($arr)` knows not to sort array as it should, so just in case add     `$arr=array_values($arr);` on the end #EDITED

PHP reference of `ksort()` is on [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Answer (score 0):

You may use this workaround.

Define this function somewhere:

```
function removeArrElement($inArr, $elementNr) {

    for ($i = $elementNr; $i < count($inArr) - 1; $i++) {
        $inArr[$i] = $inArr[$i + 1];
    }
    unset($inArr[count($inArr) - 1]);

    return $inArr;
}
```

And then, when you want to remove the specific element from $yourArray, do this:

```
$yourArray = removeArrElement($yourArray, $nthElement);
```

I feel it's not the most efficient way to do this, but it works fine.